# Multipart/form-data request to Drupal 7 REST server/Services module returns FALSE with 200 status code on file upload

Tags: web-services, drupal-7, http-post, httpresponse

I have been working for the last couple of days trying to get a file upload to my drupal REST Server and I feel like I am close but I am getting a somewhat confusing 200 status code with a response of "false".  I am a total http-request novice so I have been having some trouble.  Here is what my http-post looks like:

```
POST /?q=rest/file HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8888
Language: en-us,en;q=0.5Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8
Cookie: SESSdc0685ed01f285dab628a3700259e6bc=UAdNJUsQL5TpqEXIWFtXEcLw3wooEwqW9e0JxSz2ZHw
Content-Length: 389
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------1137522503144128232716531729

-----------------------------1137522503144128232716531729

Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"empty folder.zip\"

Content-Type: application/zip



..
 encoded content here
..   

-----------------------------1137522503144128232716531729--
```

And the response I get is simply "false with a header that looks like this:

```
(("Content-Type" "application/json") ("Connection" "Keep-Alive") ("Keep-Alive" "timeout=5, max=100") ("Content-Length" "5") ("Vary" "Accept") ("ETag" "\"1328910809\"") ("Cache-Control" "no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0") ("Last-Modified" "Fri, 10 Feb 2012 21:53:29 +0000") ("Expires" "Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT") ("X-Powered-By" "PHP/5.3.6") ("Server" "Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/0.9.8r DAV/2 PHP/5.3.6") ("Date" "Fri, 10 Feb 2012 21:53:29 GMT") ("Status" "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"))
```

and status code 200.  Also, the file is does not actually show up in the Drupal file system.  Could the problem be that I need to specify where to put it?  I snooped the http-post from the actual Drupal form and it looks almost identical to my post accept it has many more pieces of content.

Comment: a 200 status code just tells you that the server received your request and processed it- not whether the request received was processed successfully, if that makes sense. Can you provide the fields string the RESTful service is expecting, as well as yours?

Comment: That does make sense, thank you Kevin.  Hmm, this could be part of my problems, I'm not really sure what a "field string" is.  Sorry for my noobishness.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string

Comment: Oh gotcha, well I have defined a rest server with address rest so to acess the rest server I need a ?q=rest now I have also enabled the "file resource" which will allow me to CRUD a file.  So  the querry string it expects is ?q=rest/file which is what I send.  Similarly I have enabled the user resource and I have successfully completed a post to ?q=rest/user/login which is the querry string it requires to login (this in turn returned the session cookie which I am passing to the file request).  Is this what you were asking for?